# Places in Bash where pattern matching is done by regex?

Tags: bash

There are several places in Bash where pattern matching is used.

1. Is pattern matching in Bash  done either by regex, or by globbing (same style as in filename expansion)?
2. In Bash, is pattern matching done by regex only used in `[[..]]` with `=~` operator? Not elsewhere?

   Are there other places where pattern matching is done by regex?

Comment: No, just within double brackets using the `=~` operator.

Comment: Thanks.  In Bash, is pattern matching done by regex only used in `[[...]]` with `=~` operator? not elsewhere?

Comment: @glennjackman, that's the answer.  Might as well post it.

Comment: The answer is in the bash manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> When the == and != operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is  considered  a  pattern  and matched  according  to  the  rules described below under Pattern Matching, as if the extglob shell option were   enabled.

For `=~`:

> An  additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched  accordingly (as in  regex(3)).

**So, `regex(3)` is only used for matching pattern in case of `=~`**

---

Else, it is done as described below:

> Pathname Expansion:
>
> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set, bash scans each word for the characters *, ?, and  [.  If  one  of  these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern (see Pattern Matching below).

> [**Pattern Matching**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)
>
> Any character that appears in a pattern, other than the special pattern characters  described  below,  matches itself. The  NUL  character  may  not  occur in a pattern.  A backslash escapes the following character; the escaping backslash is discarded when matching.  The special pattern characters must be quoted if they  are  to be matched literally.

Also visit **extglob** which extends several pattern matching operators